# How to smooth an image with a 3x3 kernel

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to smooth an image, by looping through its pixels, calculating the average of a 3x3 patch and then applying the average to all 9 pixels in this patch.

Code:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import cv2 as cv
    from PIL import Image


    # 1. Load Image
    name = 'ebay.png'
    img = cv.imread(name) #import image

    h, w = img.shape[:2]


    # 2. Smooth with kernel size 3

    for y in range(0, w, 3):
        for x in range(0, h, 3):     
            px1 = img[x][y] #0/0
            px2 = img[x][y+1] #0/1
            px3 = img[x][y+2] #0/2
            px4 = img[x+1][y] #1/0
            px5 = img[x+1][y+1] #1/1
            px6 = img[x+1][y+2] #1/2
            px7 = img[x+2][y] #2/0
            px8 = img[x+2][y+1] #2/1
            px9 = img[x+2][y+2] #2/2

            average = np.average(px1 + px2 + px3 + px4 + px5 + px6 + px7 + px8 + px9)    

            img[x][y] =  average  #0/0
            img[x][y+1] = average   #0/1
            img[x][y+2] = average   #0/2
            img[x+1][y] = average   #1/0
            img[x+1][y+1] = average   #1/1
            img[x+1][y+2] = average  #1/2
            img[x+2][y] = average  #2/0
            img[x+2][y+1] = average   #2/1
            img[x+2][y+2] = average  #2/2

# 3. Transform the resulting image into pgm format and save result        

new_image = Image.fromarray(img)
new_image.save('new.png')

# 4. Show image

new_image.show()

However this just makes my new image just very pixely and not smooth at all.
```

I am assuming that I am doing something wrong here:

```
average = np.average(px1 + px2 + px3 + px4 + px5 + px6 + px7 + px8 + px9)
```

since, when I am using just px5 as an average the new image looks much better (but still not very smoothy). Please see image below:

Original Image:
[image: Original Image]

What my code is doing right now:
[image: What my code is doing right now...]

Result when I am using px5 as average:
[image: Result when I am using px5 as average]

Result when adding all px's and dividing by 9:
[image]

Comment: You’re computing the average of the sum of the values. That is of course equal to the sum of the values. You should sum and divide by 9 instead. But cast to a larger type first. Adding 9 uint8 values is likely overflowing the result.

Comment: Next, write the result of the average only to the middle pixel, not to all 3x3 pixels in the neighborhood. And write it to a separate output image. You cannot do this operation in place, as it will affect the result for the later pixels.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks. But what do you mean with 'casting to a larger type'? How do I do this?

Comment: 200 + 200 = 145 in modulo 256 arithmetic (which you use when computing with uint8). I don’t know what happens with numbers extracted from a numpy array, but it looks like this is your problem. `float(px1)` etc. should do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I had two issues here, which I was able to figure out thanks to @Ernie Yang and @Cris Luengo. Thank you very much for your help!

1) The issue of my average calculation was that it was overflowing I was summing up the pixel values. That is why the result was looking weird since it was wrapping around. So I had to change:

```
average = np.average(px1 + px2 + px3 + px4 + px5 + px6 + px7 + px8 + px9)
```

to:

```
average = px1/9. + px2/9. + px3/9. + px4/9. + px5/9. + px6/9. + px7/9. + px8/9. + px9/9.
```

2) However, this did not smooth my image, since I was just assigning the average value to all 9 pixels within the patch. So this caused the picture to be pixelated and not smoothed. Therefore I had to write the result of the average only to the middle pixel, not to all 3x3 pixels in the neighborhood. I also had to write it to a separate output image. You cannot do this operation in place, as it will affect the result for the later pixels.

Correct code sample:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import cv2 as cv
    from PIL import Image
    import scipy.ndimage as ndimage
    from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter


    # 1. Load Image
    name = 'ebay.png'
    img = cv.imread(name) #import image


    h, w = img.shape[:2]
    smoothedImage = cv.imread(name) #initialize second image


    # 2. Smooth with with kernel size 3

    for y in range(0, w-2):
        for x in range(0, h-2):     
            px1 = img[x][y] #0/0
            px2 = img[x][y+1] #0/1
            px3 = img[x][y+2] #0/2
            px4 = img[x+1][y] #1/0
            px5 = img[x+1][y+1] #1/1
            px6 = img[x+1][y+2] #1/2
            px7 = img[x+2][y] #2/0
            px8 = img[x+2][y+1] #2/1
            px9 = img[x+2][y+2] #2/2

            average = px1/9. + px2/9. + px3/9. + px4/9. + px5/9. + px6/9. + px7/9. + px8/9. + px9/9.

            smoothedImage[x+1][y+1] = average   #1/1

    # 3. Transform the resulting image into pgm format and save result        

    new_image = Image.fromarray(smoothedImage)
    new_image.save('new.png')

    # 4. Show image

    new_image.show()
```

Original Image:
[image]

Smoothed Image:
[image]

Edit:

> Hey folks, I am back from my afternoon nap. 
>   I had quite a few interesting thoughts, here is my improved code now:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from PIL import Image
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter


# 1. Load Image
name = 'ebay.png'
img = cv.imread(name) #import image
h, w = img.shape[:2]
kernel = 5
radius = (kernel-1)/2

img2 = np.zeros((h, w, 3), dtype = 'uint8') #new image to paint on

    def pxIsInImgRange(x, y):
        if (0<=x) and (x < w): 
                if (0<=y) and (y < h):
                    return True
        return False

    # 2. Smoothing the shit out

    for x in range (-radius, w+radius):
        for y in range (-radius, h+radius):

            if pxIsInImgRange(x,y): 

                    px = 0

                    for vx2 in range (-radius, radius+1):
                        for vy2 in range (-radius, radius+1):
                            x2 = x + vx2
                            y2 = y + vy2
                            if pxIsInImgRange(x2,y2):

                                px = px + (img[y2][x2]/float((kernel*kernel)))
                            else:
                                px = px + 0 


                    img2[y][x] = px

    # 3. Save image                

    new_image = Image.fromarray(img2)
    new_image.save('new.png')

    # 4. Show image

    new_image.show()
```

New result with kernel of 5:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
average = np.average(px1 + px2 + px3 + px4 + px5 + px6 + px7 + px8 + px9)
```

is acutally summing over the values not averaging those,

```
average = (px1 + px2 + px3 + px4 + px5 + px6 + px7 + px8 + px9)/9
```

should give you what you want.

Also for doing such task, scipy.signal.convolve2d is the best tool. See doc and example below.

https://www.google.com/search?q=scipy.signal.convolve2d&oq=scipy.signal.convolve2d&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. However adding alle px's and dividing by 9 did not fix my problem. Please the updated question.

Comment: Try this ```average2 = [np.average([px1 , px2 , px3 , px4 , px5 , px6 , px7 , px8 , px9])]*3```

Comment: The result stays exactly the same as my initial code :/

Comment: The issue of /9 was that these seems to be unsigned 8 bit int. So it was overflowing when you did the summing. That is why the result was looking weird since it was wrapping around.

Comment: But with your solution the smoothed image still loos very, very bad :/ Do you have an idea what else is wrong?

Comment: Try to delete the new.png, I was seeing some update issue for mine so i was looking to the old file. Also this has to work ```average =  px1/9. + px2/9. + px3/9. + px4/9. + px5/9. + px6/9. + px7/9. + px8/9. + px9/9.```

Comment: The issue was the data type it is 8 bit unsigned, so when you add them they overflow.